# Calculating number of permutations given N repeats allowed

Tags: combinations

It's not difficult to find a formula to calculate the number of permutations given no repeats or any number of repeats. However, I am trying to find a way of calculating the number of permutations if a choice can only be made, say, twice.

For example, given the numbers 1-9, how many permutations of a five-number sequence are there, given that the numbers 1-9 may be repeated (but only once)?

Valid combinations include 12345, 15233 (two 3s), 89349 (two 9s), 10130 (two 1s, two 0s).
Invalid combinations include 14333 and 10101.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer to the research paper:
Haim Mendelson (1981), On permutations with limited repetition, Journal of combinatorial theory, Series A, vol. 30

The paper provides the following recursive equations, with $n$ the number of objects, $r$ the size of the permutation, and $s$ the number of possible repetitions for each object
\begin{align}
f(n,r+1,s)&=n f(n,r,s)-n\left(^r_s\right)f(n-1,r-s,s) \quad \textrm{ for } n=2,3,... ; r \ge s\\
f(n,r,s)&=n^r \quad \textrm{ for } n=1,2,3,\dots;r \le s\\
f(1,r,s)&=0 \quad \textrm{ for } r>s
\end{align}

The paper gives the following explanation for the first equation:

"There are $f(n,r,s)$ ways to select the first $r$ elements without repeating any object more than $s$ times. Out of these, there are $\left(^r_s\right)f(n-1,r-s,s)$ r-permutations with a given object exaclty $s$ times. Thus, out of the $nf(n,r,s)$ possibilities attained by appending an r-permutation with limited repetition $s$ with an $(r+1)$st element, $n\left(^r_s\right)f(n-1,r-s,s)$ will violate the upper limit $s$."

The second equation is the case when the number of repetitions is larger than the size of the permutation (identical to unlimited repetitions).