# Permutations with global limited repetition

Tags: combinatorics

What is the number of permutations of $m$ objects in $n$ spaces such that there are exactly $l$ repetitions in the permutation?

for example,
if $m = 5, n = 7, l = 4$

then $$a_1, a_1, a_1, a_3, a_3, a_4,a_4$$
is a legal sequence (4 repetitions, $a_1$ twice, $a_3$ once and $a_4$ once) but

$$a_1, a_2, a_3, a_1, a_3, a_5, a_3$$ is not (only 3 repetitions).
and neither is 
$$a_1,a_1,a_1,a_1,a_1,a_1,a_1$$ legal.

The main difference of this problem from other posts such as
[Calculating number of permutations given N repeats allowed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1145001/calculating-number-of-permutations-given-n-repeats-allowed/1145074#1145074)
is that my number of repeats is global, i.e I require that the number of repetitions of all objects together is exactly l.

Comment: This seems like a tough one.  If I have understood the query correclty, then (for example), if $n = 4, m = 2,$ and $l = 2$ then you could have either $x_1,x_1,x_2,x_2 : \binom{4}{2}$ or $x_1, x_1, x_1, x_2 : \binom{4}{1}$ or $x_2, x_2, x_2, x_1 : \binom{4}{1}.$  Then the total would be $(6 + 4 +4 = 14).$  This one is no walk in the park.

Comment: Where is *m=5* figuring ? Also, if you have, say, $a_1, a_1, a_1$ it is normally considered as *three* repetitions of $a_1$

Comment: @trueblueanil $m=5$ means that there are $m$ distinct elements that may be used in the sequence: $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_5.$  Although your point about the connotation of repetitions is well taken, it is also irrelevant to the query.  The OP has **unambiguously** defined how repetitions are to be counted, and the query must be attacked under the OP's (arbitrary) definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pick the elements to be in the sequence that are going to be repeated(say $k$ of them) and then consider the repetitions by constructing a sequence $x_i=\text{# times object i repeats},$ so that
$$\sum _{i=1}^kx_i=l,\, x_i\geq 1.$$
Notice that if we call $k$ the ones that are going to be repeated, then $n-(l+k)$ are non repeated elements.
So your expression is
$$\sum _{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}\binom{m-k}{n-(l+k)}\sum _{x_1+\cdots +x_k=l}\binom{n}{\underbrace{1,\cdots ,1}_{n-(l+k)},x_1+1,\cdots ,x_k+1}.$$
Now, if this can be expressed in easier terms seems a problem for generating functions, the problem being multivariate by nature.

Comment: Would the formula be simpler if I asked for at most l repetitions?

Comment: You will have to define to me "simpler", the problem is that one has to take care of each repeated term by a separate factorial, that is why the second sum is not expressed in easier terms(as far as I can see). If you do it for at most $l,$ we will have another sum, actually. Not sure if anything will be simplified. Is this a problem for research? If so I would suggest coding this and trying to search for some OEIS sequence fixing some of the variables involved.

Comment: @Phicar would you add an edit with this example please because I can't understand exactly what **k** and some parts of formula should be filled. The example is: all the permutations of 10-digit numbers from digits 0 to 9 with global repetition of 3, like: 9576545100, 9901286787, 7890000234.

Comment: @phicar is it possible to get number of variations in a range of numbers with only knowing the **l** and not **k**? I mean just knowing there are for example 3 repetitions in numbers that we want and we do not know which digits are repeated.